# c2hs bind both typedef and function

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, c2hs

I am trying to properly create haskell bindings for function in C, that is split up in 2 files.

file1.h: `typedef const char* fmi2GetTypesPlatformTYPE(void);`

file2.h: `__declspec(dllexport) fmi2GetTypesPlatformTYPE fmi2GetTypesPlatform;`

To match this in Haskell I have created a similar structure, but this is where the trouble is.

file1.chs: `type fmi2GetTypesPlatformTYPE = {#type fmi2GetTypesPlatformTYPE#}`

How do I create a Haskell function pointer using this type? I have imported the file with `{#import file1 #}`, but I am lost on how to accomplish the last part.

See https://github.com/haskell/c2hs/issues/142
I will post the answer once resolved (unless Ian-ross beats me to it :) )

Comment: In the usual way? c2hs may provide some help but you can do it very straightforwardly with just the FFI - see [FunPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html).

Comment: I was hoping to keep all the configuration using c2hs